# Wagtail bakerydemo 2.0 requirements fail to install

Tags: wagtail

I want to use the Wagtail 2.0 bakerydemo, and I get an error during `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  The error is in compiling `uwsgi`.

No doubt the problem is in my setup - this must work for tons of other people.  What have I done wrong?

My environment:

AWS Ubuntu

Virtual environment made with `--python=python3.6`

```
(venv_bakerydemo-2.0) [ 2 ][ubuntu][ip-172-31-84-0]
[~/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/bakerydemo]
$  python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Output from `uname -a`:

```
(venv_bakerydemo-2.0) [ 0 ][ubuntu][ip-172-31-84-0]
[~/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/bakerydemo]
$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-84-0 4.4.0-1052-aws #61-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 23:05:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  This is my second attempt, so many of the requirements are already available.

```
(venv_bakerydemo-2.0) [ 1 ][ubuntu][ip-172-31-84-0]
[~/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/bakerydemo]
$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
Requirement already satisfied: Django<2.1,>=2.0 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: django-dotenv==1.4.1 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied: elasticsearch==2.4.1 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied: wagtail<2.1,>=2.0 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: wagtailfontawesome<1.2,>=1.1.3 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 8))
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow==4.0.0 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 9))
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url==0.4.1 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 3))
Collecting uwsgi==2.0.14 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 4))
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.14.tar.gz
Collecting psycopg2==2.7.3.1 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 5))
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.3.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting whitenoise==3.2.2 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 6))
  Using cached whitenoise-3.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting boto==2.45.0 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 7))
  Using cached boto-2.45.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-storages==1.6.5 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 8))
  Using cached django_storages-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore==1.7.10 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 10))
  Using cached botocore-1.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting aws-requests-auth==0.4.0 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 11))
Collecting django-redis==4.8.0 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 12))
  Using cached django_redis-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django_cache_url==2.0.0 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 13))
  Using cached django_cache_url-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting awscli==1.11.23 (from -r requirements/production.txt (line 15))
  Using cached awscli-1.11.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<2.0,>=1.8 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from elasticsearch==2.4.1->-r requirements/base.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework<4.0,>=3.1.3 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4<5.0,>=4.5.1 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: Unidecode<1.0,>=0.04.14 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.11.1 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib<1,>=0.999 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: django-modelcluster<5.0,>=4.0 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: django-taggit<1.0,>=0.22.2 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: django-treebeard<5.0,>=4.2.0 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: draftjs-exporter<2.1,>=2.0 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: Willow<1.2,>=1.1 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Pillow==4.0.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 9))
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.7.10->-r requirements/production.txt (line 10))
  Using cached jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore==1.7.10->-r requirements/production.txt (line 10))
  Using cached docutils-0.14-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.7.10->-r requirements/production.txt (line 10))
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting redis>=2.10.0 (from django-redis==4.8.0->-r requirements/production.txt (line 12))
  Using cached redis-2.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 (from awscli==1.11.23->-r requirements/production.txt (line 15))
  Using cached rsa-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 (from awscli==1.11.23->-r requirements/production.txt (line 15))
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9 (from awscli==1.11.23->-r requirements/production.txt (line 15))
  Using cached s3transfer-0.1.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 (from awscli==1.11.23->-r requirements/production.txt (line 15))
  Using cached colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.11.1->wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail<2.1,>=2.0->-r requirements/base.txt (line 7))
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli==1.11.23->-r requirements/production.txt (line 15))
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi ... error
  Complete output from command /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cv2cy12v/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpvpu__cq8pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
  Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
  detected CPU cores: 1
  configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.14\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="14" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
  *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/utils.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/protocol.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/socket.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/logging.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_utils.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/emperor.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/notify.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/async.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_checks.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fifo.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/offload.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/io.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/static.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/websockets.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/spooler.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/snmp.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/exceptions.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/setup_utils.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/clock.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/init.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/buffer.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/reader.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/writer.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/alarm.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cron.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/hooks.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/plugins.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/lock.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cache.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/daemons.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/errors.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/hash.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_events.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/chunked.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/queue.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/event.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/signal.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/strings.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/progress.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/timebomb.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/ini.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fsmon.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mount.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/metrics.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/plugins_builder.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sharedarea.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/rpc.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/gateway.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/loop.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cookie.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/querystring.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/rb_timers.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/transformations.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/uwsgi.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/base.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/uwsgi.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/http.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/fastcgi.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/scgi.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/puwsgi.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] lib/linux_ns.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/zlib.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/yaml.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/ssl.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/legion.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/xmlconf.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/dot_h.o
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config_py.o
  *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
  [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
  In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:0:
  plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi, psycopg2, whitenoise, boto, django-storages, jmespath, docutils, python-dateutil, botocore, aws-requests-auth, redis, django-redis, django-cache-url, pyasn1, rsa, PyYAML, s3transfer, colorama, awscli
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
    Complete output from command /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cv2cy12v/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-iy0jpzd_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/include/site/python3.6/uwsgi:
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 1
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.14\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="14" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    core/protocol.o is up to date
    core/socket.o is up to date
    core/logging.o is up to date
    core/master.o is up to date
    core/master_utils.o is up to date
    core/emperor.o is up to date
    core/notify.o is up to date
    core/mule.o is up to date
    core/subscription.o is up to date
    core/stats.o is up to date
    core/sendfile.o is up to date
    core/async.o is up to date
    core/master_checks.o is up to date
    core/fifo.o is up to date
    core/offload.o is up to date
    core/io.o is up to date
    core/static.o is up to date
    core/websockets.o is up to date
    core/spooler.o is up to date
    core/snmp.o is up to date
    core/exceptions.o is up to date
    core/config.o is up to date
    core/setup_utils.o is up to date
    core/clock.o is up to date
    core/init.o is up to date
    core/buffer.o is up to date
    core/reader.o is up to date
    core/writer.o is up to date
    core/alarm.o is up to date
    core/cron.o is up to date
    core/hooks.o is up to date
    core/plugins.o is up to date
    core/lock.o is up to date
    core/cache.o is up to date
    core/daemons.o is up to date
    core/errors.o is up to date
    core/hash.o is up to date
    core/master_events.o is up to date
    core/chunked.o is up to date
    core/queue.o is up to date
    core/event.o is up to date
    core/signal.o is up to date
    core/strings.o is up to date
    core/progress.o is up to date
    core/timebomb.o is up to date
    core/ini.o is up to date
    core/fsmon.o is up to date
    core/mount.o is up to date
    core/metrics.o is up to date
    core/plugins_builder.o is up to date
    core/sharedarea.o is up to date
    core/rpc.o is up to date
    core/gateway.o is up to date
    core/loop.o is up to date
    core/cookie.o is up to date
    core/querystring.o is up to date
    core/rb_timers.o is up to date
    core/transformations.o is up to date
    core/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/base.o is up to date
    proto/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/http.o is up to date
    proto/fastcgi.o is up to date
    proto/scgi.o is up to date
    proto/puwsgi.o is up to date
    lib/linux_ns.o is up to date
    core/zlib.o is up to date
    core/yaml.o is up to date
    core/ssl.o is up to date
    core/legion.o is up to date
    core/xmlconf.o is up to date
    [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/dot_h.o
    [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config_py.o
    *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
    [x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
    In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:0:
    plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cv2cy12v/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-iy0jpzd_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/venv_bakerydemo-2.0/include/site/python3.6/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cv2cy12v/uwsgi/
(venv_bakerydemo-2.0) [ 1 ][ubuntu][ip-172-31-84-0]
[~/repos/bakerydemo-2.0-here/bakerydemo]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the python3 development headers - on Ubuntu, these can be installed with `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`. Having said that, uwsgi is only really used for production deployments - if you continue to have problems installing it, it's safe enough to comment out the `uwsgi` line from requirements/production.txt to proceed.